# Monolog, how to log PHP array into console?

Tags: php, monolog

I am using the browser handler to log message into JS console

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Monolog\Logger;
use Monolog\Handler\BrowserConsoleHandler;

$log = new Logger('name');
$log->pushHandler(new BrowserConsoleHandler);

$data = array(1,2,3,4);

// add records to the log
$log->addWarning('Foo');
```

I am wondering, is it possible to log array such as `$data` into the console which reassemble the array content?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this:

```
$log->addWarning('Foo: ' . var_export($data, true));
```

Comment: Feel I should add, 5 years on from this answer, that the correct approach now is to use `$log->addWarning('Foo', $data);` as per Colin Smillie's answer, below. https://stackoverflow.com/a/39025294/2286736

Answer (score 9):

The best approach ( from the 2nd half of Felix's answer ) for an array is:

```
$log->addWarning('Foo:' , $data);
```

The AddWarning will accept an array as the 2nd parameter and format it properly in the browser.

Using var_export will convert to a string and not format the array properly in the browser console.

Answer (score 3):

Also, you can try this:

```
$log->addWarning('Foo: ' . print_r($data, true));
```

Or

```
$log->addWarning('Foo:' , $data);
```

Comment: $log->addWarning('Foo: ' . print_r($data, true));  does not work, Output is "1"

Comment: It means that your $data is 1.

Comment: The 2nd half of the answer is correct and the better approach.